# Reformat Code in Notepad++

Tags: editor, notepad++, code-formatting

Is there a function (and shortcut) to reformat code in Notepad++

Like [<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> in Eclipse](https://archive.is/fyie6#selection-3111.0-3119.16)?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

TextFX hasn't been updated for a long time. A more powerful choice is UniversalIndentGUI.

Comment: When you have no admin-rights, you should check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29116453/6287240)

Comment: It's been a while since this thread was active, but I must say TextFX is -although not maintained any more for a very long time- one of the BEST plugins ever made for NPP.  Despite its age, it's still fully functional which means the developer has been very keen in thinking a long time ahead with his plugin features.  I needed to reformat C-source code and with TextFX it's a breeze...

Comment: I agree with GeertVc. I will use IDEs for most programming, but when using Notepad++ (usually for C code) the whole point for me is to be using a lightweight editor. So in this case, I don't prefer "a more powerful" plugin, just one that's quick, simple, and light.

Comment: TextFX2 is now available. Install from the Plugin manager. Select TextFX Edit / Re-indent C++ code.

Answer (score 23):

If you are working with C++ then you can use the TextFX features. Go to

```
TextFX->Edit->Reindent C++ code
```

And regarding shortcuts you can always modify your shortcuts for NPP by using

```
Settings->Shortcut mapper
```

in this case go to

```
Settings->Shortcut mapper->Plugin commands: #141
```

and modify it to **CTRL + SHIFT + F**.

Comment: Thanks. I downloaded TextFX via the plugin manager. Actually I wanted to reformat Java code. Although it is called Reindent C++ code, it worked for my Java files. :-)

Comment: thanks for the saver alem :)

Comment: There is no TextFX menu item in version 7.9.1.

Comment: TextFX2 is now available. Install from the Plugin manager. Select TextFX Edit / Re-indent C++ code.

Comment: I installed TextFX, but there is no TextFX->Edit menu. Plenty of other options and tools under the TextFX menu, but no Edit submenu.