# UniversalIndentGUI plugin does not work without admin rights

Tags: notepad++, universalindentgui

Without running Notepad++ as admin, UniversalIndentGUI will delete my work or do something similar to deleting a good chunk. With administrator, it performs fine.

I thought it was some settings I created so I re-installed Notepad++ but nothing seems to have changed. Perhaps I didn't do a clean uninstall?

I'm running windows 8, and this probably has to do with a problem with notepad++ being in the default `C:\Program Files (x86)` folder.

Is there a alternate to this or some way to troubleshoot?

Here's the error, I also reinstalled it so that it would use `%AppData%` for plugins, but for some reason I don't think it is. So I may need help with that instead.  I originally installed to not use `%AppData%` before the re-installs.

> Indenter returned with exit code: 1
>   Indent console output was: 
>   (STDOUT):
>   (STDERR):Could not open options file C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\plugins\uigui\temp.astylerc
>
> Callstring was: "C:/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/plugins/uigui/indenters/astyle.exe" indentinput.cpp --options="C:/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/plugins/uigui/temp/.astylerc"

Comment: I still need help with this problem.. UIGUI isn't working for me.. :/ I would like to switch over from TextFx..

Answer (score 9):

I have fixed this (or a similar) problem this way:

1. Run Notepad++ with Administrator rights.
2. Install/reinstall UniversalIndentGUI using the Plugin manager.
3. Go to C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\plugins\uigui
4. Give Modify and Write permissions to Users for "config" and "temp" directories:

   1. Go to Properties -> Security -> Edit
   2. Select Users
   3. Check Modify
   4. Click Apply
5. Restart Notepad++ with User rights and use UniversalIndentGUI.

Answer (score 2):

One of the install screens for Notepad++ has a check box for "**Don't use %APPDATA%**". When the box is checked then Notepad++ stores its configuration files in its installation directory. When the box is not checked the configuration files are stored in the user's appdata folder. On my Windows 8.1 computer the folder is `C:\Users\{{username}}\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++`.

On many computers folders within `C:\Program Files (x86)\` are protected so non-admin users cannot modify them. Hence the successes you saw when running as admin and the failures when running as a non-admin.

This check box in the install options has been available for several versions of Notepad++, I remember it being available when Windows 7 was fairly new. I have just checked and it is available with Notepad++ version 6.7.5.